# If there is a total order on $A$ and there is surjection $A\rightarrow B$ then can $B$ be totally ordered?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, order-theory

I constructed a following theorem and I wish to (dis)prove it:

> Let $\leq$ be a total order on $A$ and let there be surjection $\varphi:A\rightarrow B$. Then there exists total order on $B$.

This seems really trivial and obvious to me. For any $b_1,b_2\in B$, because $\varphi$ is surjection, we can find $a_1,a_2\in A$ such that $\varphi(a_1)=b_1$ and $\varphi(a_2)=b_2$. Then, if I define $R\subseteq B\times B$ as follows:$$(b_1,b_2)\in R\Leftrightarrow (a_1,a_2)\in\leq$$
where, as mentioned, $b_1=\varphi(a_1),b_2=\varphi(a_2)$, am I done?

EDIT: this is obviously wrong. What I'm dealing with is a set $A$ of all possible strings of finite length of given alphabet $\Sigma$ (with some additional, not so important property, thus in fact $A\subsetneq \Sigma^*$). The total order of $\Sigma^*$ is given

1.) by the length of the strings,

2.) lexicographically (I assume, there exists some total ordering of an alphabet)

Now because $A\subsetneq \Sigma^*$ by the property of linear order, $A$ is lineary ordered too.
Now to any $b\in B$ i assign some $a\in A$ such that $a\mapsto b$. Giving surjection $A\rightarrow B$

Comment: What if $b_1=\varphi(a_1)=\varphi(a_1')$ with $a_1\neq a_1'$, $a_1\leq a_2$ and $a_2\leq a_1'$? It seems not to be well defined since it depends on the preimage you take.

Comment: But these $a_1$ and $a_2$ are not necessary unique. What if there are also $c_1$,$c_2$ such that $\varphi(c_1)=b_1$,$\varphi(c_2)=b_2$ and you have $(c_1,c_2)\notin\leq$?

Comment: True, let me edit my original post, i have different idea.

Comment: By the way, since you didn't ask for a total order $B$ compatible with $\varphi$ in any sense, this might interest you https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37272/are-all-sets-totally-ordered

Comment: Well, I know something about that, but, as there mentioned, it is equivalent to AC, which I'm not sure that i want to assume. In fact, if i could assume that anything can be totally ordered then half of my proof I'm working on, is pointless.
To my different idea: It actually failed too, but let me give more details on what order I have etc.

Comment: Just as a simple example, if you want to construct the total order of $B$ from the one on $A$ in some way, how would you do it for $\Bbb R\to S^1$ given by $t\to e^{it}$?

Comment: @Arthur good example. So basically, do you guys say that i need an injection, thus a bijection, right?

Comment: Then I could have $b_1=\varphi(a_1)=\varphi(a_1')$ and that would imply $a_1=a_1'$ or basically, because i would be able to compare $a_1, a_1'$ i would be able to compare $\varphi(a_1),\varphi(a_1')$ and because I have a bijection the converse would be true aswell and my defined ordering would work, am i right?

Comment: Or else, I can start assigning $b$ members to $a$ constructing a bijection from $A\rightarrow C\subset B$ and by the property of linear ordering, $C$ is totally ordered and thus $A$ can be totally ordered.

Comment: If you have a bijection then for sure you can send the order from $A$ to $B$ by $b_1\leq b_2\Leftrightarrow \varphi^{-1}(b_1)\leq\varphi^{-1}(b_2)$.

Comment: Can anyone say what happens without the axiom of choice ? Is "for every set $A$, there is a totally orderable set $B$ and a surjection $B\to A$" provable in ZF ? Implies AC ? Is strictly inbetween ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you accept the axiom of choice, then any set $B$ can be well-ordered. This gives you a total order on $B$. However, there is *no* relation to the order $\le_A$ on $A$, and that is probably not what you want.

Using the axiom of choice again, you get a *section* for $p$ which is a function $i : B \to A$ such that $p \circ i = id_B$. Obviuosly $i$ is injective.
In concrete situations you may even be able to construct *explicitly* a section for $p$.

Given any section, the subset $i(B)$ inherits an order $\le_{i(B)}$ from $A$. This is again a total order. Now you can give $B$ the unique order $\le_i$ defined by $b \le_i b_2$ if $i(b_1) \le_A i(b_2)$. Then $(B,\le_i)$ and $(i(B),\le_{i(B)})$ are isomorphic as ordered sets. In general $\le_i$ depends on the choice of a section, so you get a whole collection of total orders which are somehow related to $\le_A$. But you cannot expect that there exists a section $i$ such that $a_1 \le_A a_2$ implies $p(a_1) \le_i p(a_2)$ for all $a_1,a_2$.

Moreover, if there exists an order $\le_B$ on $B$ (which is not required to be a total order) such that $p$ is order-preserving, then for any section $i$ the orders $\le_B$ and $\le_i$ agree. In particular, $\le_B$ is a total order.

(1) Let $b_1 \le_i b_2$. Then $i(b_1) \le_A i(b_2)$ and $b_1 = p(i(b_1) \le_B p(i(b_2) = b_2$.

(2) Let $b_1 \le_B b_2$. If $b_1 \le_i b_2$, we are done. If $b_2 \le_i b_1$, use (1) to see $b_2 \le_B b_1$. Therefore $b_1 = b_2$ and in particular $b_1 \le_i b_2$.

Comment: If I can make some 'section' of P that is, say $P'=\{p_1,...p_k\}$ and from this set i choose, wlog $p_1$ as the minimal element (it exists, because $P$ is totally ordered, because $P'\subseteq P$ and then construct an injection thus bijection and the order will work. If i declare the function explicitly, does that  mean I am using AC?

Comment: @MichalDvořák There are situations where you do not need AC. For example, if you know that each $p^{-1}(b)$ has a minimum, you get a section for $p$ by defining $i(b) = \min p^{-1}(b)$. This occurs when all $p^{-1}(b)$ are finite or when $A$ is well-ordered. But certainly you need "good luck".